# GCE How do I get the Advanced settings > SSL for Custom Domains option to appear?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

From the docs:

> Security > Show more > Advanced settings > SSL for Custom Domains.
>   (This link is only visible if you have set up a subdomain.)

I have set up [my domain].com and a cname-- www.[my domain].com using google domains. They point to my site hosted on a google virtual machine. All is working fine.

Now, I would like to add always-on SSL. I created a google apps account. Both [my domain].com and www.[my domain].com appear in the domains screen on the https://admin.google.com/[my domain].com/AdminHome#Domains: page but I still don't see the Advanced settings > SSL for Custom Domains option. Evidently the subdomain setup lacks some important factor. How do I get the Advanced settings > SSL for Custom Domains option to appear?

Answer (score 1):

SSL setup will vary depending on where your site is hosted - app engine or compute engine.

If your app is hosted on app engine, you need to go to:
Security > Show more > SSL for App Engine Apps

The URL to this setting page would look like this:
https://admin.google.com/[my domain].com/AdminHome#SecuritySettings:flyout=ssl

In case your app is hosted on compute engine, you may need to set up HTTPS load balancing. Follow these links:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/https-load-balancing-nginx

Comment: The app is hosted on the compute engine. How do I configure load balancing to deliver always-on ssl on the "naked" domain name? The www  domain name should direct to the "naked" (always-on) SSL https://[my-domain].com I have the SSL certificate files from Comodo.